# /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start command in HTOP running consistently. Is it a bot?

Tags: apache-2.2, www-data, htop

I have got a VPS with six websites running on it. None of them get very much traffic at all, maybe 10-20 a day each.

As far as I am aware, `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start` should represent a user hitting a site. (user in htop is `www-data`.)

I am watching `htop` for this VPS, and it is constantly hitting over and over. The server load average is `0.58` and it typically never gets above `0.10`.

Is this something I should be concerned about? I restarted the server earlier and it stopped, but then started about 4 hours later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evidence points to CloudFlare re-crawling the websites after purging the cache. It seemed as if it wouldn't take as long, but everything I found during my research pointed to that conclusion.

If it continues, I will update this status.